# How can I add an image of photo library (or camera) in a tweet?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, ios5, twitter

I'm using the Twitter framework of iOS 5 but the `addimage` method allows only project images...
How can I pick an image from the library or the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Davide, You would need to use [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) to make the user select a photo from his Photo Library and then use the resulted UIImage as a parameter for `addImage`.

There are many tutorials out there about this, Here is one of them:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/camera/camera-application-to-take-pictures-and-save-images-to-photo-album.html